# How to fix "undefined reference SetDIBitsToDevice", even already linked library "gdi32.lib"?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, cimg

This is my first time learning about `Cimg`. I'm trying the code from the `Cimg` tutorial. I get an error message, `"undefined reference to SetDIBitsToDevice@48"`.

I am using `CodeBlocks 17.12`. I already linked to `gdi32.lib` from the Windows kit. I used the builder `option -> link setting`. It still tells me `"undefined reference to SetDIBitsToDevice@48"`.  After that, I changed to library `"libgdi32.a"` and `"gdi32"` and added the header file `"wingdi.h"` in the `"Cimg.h"` file. All do not work.

Here is the code from http://cimg.eu/reference/group__cimg__tutorial.html

```
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;
int main() {
    CImg<unsigned char> image("1.jpg"), visu(1920,1080,1,3,0);
    const unsigned char red[] = { 255,0,0 }, green[] = { 0,255,0 }, blue[] = { 0,0,255 };
    image.blur(2.5);
    CImgDisplay main_disp(image,"Click a point"), draw_disp(visu,"Intensity profile");
    while (!main_disp.is_closed() && !draw_disp.is_closed()) {
      main_disp.wait();
      if (main_disp.button() && main_disp.mouse_y()>=0) {
         const int y = main_disp.mouse_y();
         visu.fill(0).draw_graph(image.get_crop(0,y,0,0,image.width()-1,y,0,0),red,1,1,0,255,0);
         visu.draw_graph(image.get_crop(0,y,0,1,image.width()-1,y,0,1),green,1,1,0,255,0);
         visu.draw_graph(image.get_crop(0,y,0,2,image.width()-1,y,0,2),blue,1,1,0,255,0).display(draw_disp);
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I compile it except add the `#define cimg_display 0` at the head?

Comment: `lgdi32.a`??? In Code::Blocks -> Project -> Build Options -> Linker Settings -> Add >> libgdi32.a

Comment: yes, libgdi32.a, my bad.

Comment: It must be `_SetDIBitsToDevice@48` when you target x86, the standard decoration for an stdcall function.  Or plain `SetDIBitsToDevice` when you target x64.  Quite doubtful that anybody could explain the wonky `|` character.  Do make sure you copy/pasted the error message correctly.  And do consider that there are better IDEs than Code::Blocks available on Windows.

Comment: There is  `SetDIBitsToDevice@48' not '_SetDIBitsToDevice@48'. I will try another IDEs, thx for suggestion.

Comment: Surely the MSDN documentation told you "Header file: wingdi.h (include windows.h)".  Follow that instruction; do not include wingdi.h directly.

Comment: I fixed it by uninstall and  reinstall whole GCC and codeblocks. I guess there is something wrong on my building environment.